# keep getting a parse indendation error in Haskell what am I doing wrong

Tags: haskell

```
cube = x*x*x
cube xs = map cube [x | x <-xs] 
           where x mod 2 == 1
```

so I'm trying to get the odd number of the list

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: the `where` clause needs to be indented. (Haskell treats anything with the same "indentation level" as the previous line as a new statement, this is a part of the previous expression so it needs to be intended to show this.)

Comment: by the way there are a number of other issues and misunderstandings with your implementation

Comment: what are the other errors can you please help

Comment: Haskell `where` is not the same as SQL `where`.

Answer (score 3):

The above code fragment contains some errors:

1. you here use `where` as a filter, but in Haskell a where clause is used to define locally scoped variables;
2. you only define the `(x:xs)` pattern, so even if this works, it will error on the empty list;
3. `[x | x <- xs]` is just the identity function for a list, so we can omit that, furthermore it is advisable *not* to name variables the same as the "outer" variables, since that creates confusion; and
4. `x mod 2 == 1` can be replaced by [**`odd :: Integral i => i -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:odd).

We can fix this by writing it like:

```
cubeOdds2 :: Integral i => [i] -> [i]
cubeOdds2 = map cube . filter odd
    where cube x = x * x * x
```

For example:

```
Prelude> cubeOdds2 [1,4,2,5]
[1,125]
```

We here thus use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) to filter the list, such that only odd numbers are retained, and then use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to perform a mapping on these elements with `cube` as the function that takes an element and returns the mapping for that element.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems. One is incorrect syntax the other is misunderstanding what the where clause is for.  Then there's pattern matching unnecessarily.  Finally, and not strictly a problem, is a mix of list notation and higher order functions.

**Not a Where Clause**

A `where` clause is for variable bindings, such as:

```
where functionName param1 param2 = <some expression>
```

The clause is not useful for constraints over the variables.   For a list-notation style constraint just add a comma and the constraint:

```
[x | x <- list, predicate1 x, predicate2 x]
```

**Pattern Matching**

The function `cubeOdds2 (x:xs)` will bind `x` to the first element in the list then `xs` to the remaining list.  It will also fail with an exception on empty lists. 
 What you seem to want is to just operate on the list , so don't pattern match and just use a variable name such as `cubeOdds2 xs`.

**List Comprehension Notation vs Higher Order Functions**

A list comprehension is syntax like `[a | val <- list, predicate val, let a = someFunction val]`.  Higher order functions can do everything the list comprehension does, such as `map`ping the someFunction computation and `filter`ing based on the predicate.

**Some Solutions**

With these changes we have three final forms for your cubeOdds function.

First, your mix of conventions:

```
cubeOdds3 xs = map cube [x | x <- xs, x `mod` 2 == 1]
```

Second, just list comprehension:

```
cubeOdds4 xs = [cube x | x <- xs, x `mod` 2 == 1]
```

Third, just higher order functions:

```
cubeOdds5 xs = map cube (filter (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 1) xs)
```

**Code Golf**

We can even go further and use the built in `odd` function:

```
cubeOdds6 xs = [cube x | x <- xs, odd x]
```

And use point free style too:

```
cubeOdds7 = map cube . filter odd
```